Does Shibboleth have the ability to be tuned for faster authentication?
My question is "Does Shibboleth have the ability to be tuned for faster authentication?"  I am trying to do some performance tuning to make SSO faster for my end users. We have Shibboleth hitting our AD/Optimal environment, then authenticating the end users by their UPN into a Java application, rather then having to manually sign into this java web app to work.  Are there any switches/settings/etc. within Shibboleth that could provide more server resources to speed this process up?
I am currently unaware of any settings available, therefore I am asking for advice regarding this subject.

Which part is slow in particular? The IdP (SSO provider side) or the SP (webapp side)? Are you using Shibboleth on both sides, or just Shibboleth SP talking to ADFS IdP, or some other combination? Does e.g. the web browser's DevTools request log (to start with) show a specific request being unusually slow?
